# determining equation of a surface

Tags: surfaces

I was wondering if there is a way to determine the equation of a surface if three R2 linear equations are known. I work in a research lab that produces a lot of correlation equations (mx+b), and we have three mx+b equations. Is there a way to combine these three equations to produce an equation of a surface in R3?

My research involves determining three values from a sample, and these three values are all related to each other in that an increase in x can cause a change in both y and z.

If this isn't clear, I would be happy to provide more details/explanation!

Comment: So you have y and z as linear functions of x, but what's your third equation?  Seems to me you've defined a line in R3, not a surface.